# sections of higher direct image sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$, be a proper birational morphism of projective algebraic varieties with $X$ smooth. 
Denote by $R^if_* \mathcal{O}_X$, the higher direct image sheaves.

Do exists a simple way to compute the sections of such sheaves?

I want to know if the inequality $ h^0( X, R^1 f_* \mathcal{O}_X) \leq h^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) $ holds in general.

Comment: The first group needs to be $h^0(Y,R^1f_*\mathcal O_X)$. This is probably not always true, though I don't know an example; there is a not-necessarily-surjective map between the two from the Leray spectral sequence.

Comment: In general this is not true as mentioned in the previous comment. It is possible to find a smooth rational projective surface $X$ and blow down an elliptic curve to get $Y$. Then $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X=k$ supported at the singular point, so the left side is one dimensional, while the right side is zero since $X$ is rational.